# jquery mobile changePage break tabs in footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile app with two pages: `page1` and `page2`

On `page1`, I am redirecting the user to `page2` via the following code:

```js
$.mobile.changePage("/home/page2/", { transition: "slide" });
```

`Page2` has three `data-role="page"` elements in it. Each of these pages has the following in the footer:

```html
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#screen1">Screen 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#screen2">Screen 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Screen 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I navigate directly to `/home/page2` the tabs work fine. However, when I redirect the user to page2 via `changePage()`, the tabs do not work. What would cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html):

> **Linking within a multi-page document**
>
> It's important to note that if you are linking from a mobile page that
>   was loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages,
>   you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link.
>   This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the
>   Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash
>   (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the
>   hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash
>   between these two modes.

`changePage()` inherently uses Ajax to load the page and that is the cause of your problem, because only `#screen1` gets loaded.

If your app UI and logic allow you make your redirect from `Page1` to `Page2` with a link:

```html
<a href="page2.html" rel="external" data-transition="slide">Go to Page 2</a>
```

If you have to redirect programmatically consider splitting the multipage `Page2` into separate JQM pages (e.g. page21.html, page22.html, page23.html) and link them appropriately or produce your content dynamically when user clicks on navbar tabs.